# How could I split a very large JSONL file and assign every part to a process

Tags: python, json, parsing, multiprocessing

I have a really large JSONL file (14GiB, 12 Million lines) that contains records of lightning strokes around the world. What I am trying to do is to refine this dataset so that only lightning strokes that occurred in Germany remain at the end. Each line of the file contains one "strokes" list that holds many JSON objects (lightning strike). It looks like this:

```
"strokes": [
    {
        "time": 1624230617044,
        "lat": 64.298728,
        "lon": 44.536694,
        "src": 2,
        "srv": 2,
        "id": 42243883,
        "del": 1887,
        "dev": 1941
    }, #... other items
]
```

As you can see, one does not know in which country the lightning strike occurred since only latitude and longitude are given. One has to use the `reverse_geocoder` library in order to map one particular set of coordinates to the country. The method can be used as follows:

```
rg.search(strike_location)  # strike_location is a tuple that holds the gps coordinate
```

The output of the method is a json objects that holds the ISO Code of the country, 'DE' for Germany.
One way to achieve this task would be to iterate through the file, line after line and filter the data, turns out one query to the `reverse_geocoder` library needs approx. 1.5sc to complete, which makes this approach really slow.

The other approach that I've thought of consists of splitting up the file in parts and assign each part to one particular process, let's say 16 parts, so I would create 16 Process, since I have 16 CPUs on my machine. If such an approach is possible, how could that be done? Or if you have some way to improve the first approach, it would help me a lot.

Comment: What is `reverse_geocoder` _actually doing_ that makes it slow? If it's a network lookup or another IO-bound process it isn't subject to the GIL, so you can parallelize without needing multiprocessing.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text, use the text instead. Also, what is the unit "sc" in "1.5sc"? Seconds would be just "s".

Comment: Also, if it's a network lookup being done, trying to parallelize too much may get you banned from using the service at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy reverse_geocoder is not the only problem, there is also the overhead of parsing the json line + looping through the array contained in the line + writing to the output file where the lightning strokes in germany are being saved.

Comment: @YassineElBaaj, the parsing overhead doesn't matter; you don't need to parse it from the same process doing the reader. Read a line, throw it on a queue, let another process take it off the queue, parse it, and do the lookup.

Comment: BTW, have you looked into publicly available databases to do the geographic lookup yourself? It's not like the borders of Germany move often; any GIS database should be able to do the job locally for you with only publicly available data, and there are lots of good ones (PostGIS has been available for decades, f/e).

Comment: [How to import country administrative boundaries from OSM Planet to PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143426/how-to-import-country-administrative-boundaries-from-osm-planet-to-postgis-polyg) is directly relevant wrt being able to set up your own database to run local "what country are these coordinates in?" without needing to use any external service at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, the useful link specified in the thread that you just sent is not available anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I assume that the location lookup is a network request. Doing these in parallel doesn't require much CPU at all, because it's not limited by your CPU, but by how fast you can send according requests, have them processed by the service and the response being returned to you. So, in short, the number of useful parallel requests has nothing to do with your number of CPU cores.

Now, for parallel requests to a web service, you don't need multiple processes. It's enough to use e.g. threads, but you could perhaps even get away without doing the threading yourself, if the module making the requests provides parallel request support.

That said, Germany is geographically pretty restricted. Doing a simple filter by min/max latitude and longitude will probably reduce the number of candidates a lot already. Consider doing that, especially if the service doing the geomapping is free, because you don't want to abuse their resources!

Comment: I think that using this approach (applying a max/min filter on the gps coordinates) will make it more likely to lose some of the records, no ? Since it would be not 100% accurate. Correct me if I am wrong please, maybe I did not understand what you said .

Comment: @YassineElBaaj, the idea is to use the filter to exclude things that are _definitely_ outside Germany, or include things that are _definitely_ inside Germany, and do lookups only for records where there exists any question. If you do it right, no, you won't lose records.

Comment: Can we maybe continue this in private ? Public room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131639/lightning-strokes-germany

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be useful to use **Dask**
https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/

Just use **dask.dataframe.read_json** method.

Also Dask supports multi-processing and even if it is a large file, you don't have to worry because Dask use lazy loading.

Comment: Does dask do reverse geocoding? It's not the JSON parsing that's slow and needs to be parallelized.

Comment: you can use dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply for rg.search

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to complete this task using as less external libraries as possible. Also I've tried loading the content of the file with dask.dataframe.read_json, the program just stopsq after 3-4 Seconds since the file is too big ~ 14 GiB

Comment: use blocksize parameter. and Instead of loading first, it is better to specify the calculation and then load it.

Comment: @phifriday, ...it would make the answer stronger if you moved some of your supplemental notes into it, rather than just having them here in the comments. Content that's just in comments aren't considered part of the answer for voting purposes, and they're volatile -- can be deleted in a way that makes them invisible to all but moderators at any time.